# Create Win32 control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In a WinForms application I'm trying to create a Native Win32 ListBox. I do have such a minimal code, that creates the control, but the background of the ListBox is not white nor ti has the Vertical ScrollBars.

```
public partial class NativeListBox : Form
{
    public NativeListBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void NativeListBox_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListBoxEx lb = new ListBoxEx
        {
            Style = 1345523968,
            ExStyle = 512,
            Top = 10,
            Left = 10,
            Width = 220,
            Height = 300
        };

        Controls.Add(lb);    
    }
}

public class ListBoxEx : Control
{
    public int Style { get; set; }
    public int ExStyle { get; set; }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            var cp = base.CreateParams;

            cp.ClassName = "LISTBOX";
            //cp.Style |= Style;
            //cp.ExStyle |= ExStyle;
            cp.Style |= NativeMethods.WS_VSCROLL | NativeMethods.LBS_NOTIFY | NativeMethods.LBS_HASSTRINGS | NativeMethods.WS_BORDER;

            return cp;
        }
    }
}
```

Looks like something is missing. I checked this source code from .NET https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ListBox.cs,03c7f20ed985c1fc but didn't notice anything else special about creation of the ListBox in its minimal incarnation.

Any ideas what else shall be added?

Due to some other technical difficulties, I cannot use the Standard ListBox from .NET itself.

Comment: What are these technical difficulties, and why don't ask about how to solve them, rather than jumping to one particular solution (implement your own)?

Comment: Please, let's avoid this discussion, and focus on the question itself if possible. Let's say, this is an experiment on how to create native controls.

Comment: *Shrug* it's your question. You might be missing a simple solution to your actual problem, though.

Comment: ok, fine, I have a Native Win32 ListBox control that uses native messaging to paint a very complicated "tree" structure. Yes, I could spend 2-3 days and replicate that in .NET with custom drawing, but I'd like just to reuse all of that Win32 C++ code as much as possible. So I thought to create a native control, handle WndProc and copy/paste the original c++ code.

Comment: OK, have you tried inheriting `ListBox` instead of `Control`? You can [override](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.wndproc.aspx) WndProc on a ListBox-derived class.

Comment: Yes, I did that, actually I'm using the NativeWindow class to subClass any .NET native control and handle there the Win32 messages. Works ok, but I'm getting a strange error with the ListBox. https://www.dropbox.com/s/5zvvwsvbpj0ad4u/NullRef.png?dl=1